# UIScrollView doesn't show the scrollbars and doesn't scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have added UIImageView control on my page and embedded it inside UIScrollViewer ( Edit -> Embed in ... ).

The UIImageView has default image in it.

What am i trying to achieve:

1) Allow user to zoom in and out, this will be achieved using +/- control and setting the:

```
//zoom out
self.iboRealScroolView.zoomScale=self.iboRealScroolView.zoomScale-1;
//zoom in
self.iboRealScroolView.zoomScale=self.iboRealScroolView.zoomScale+1;
```

2) And allow user to scroll the zoomed in picture

**Here is a problem when i set zoom scale - scroll bars don't show up and picture is not scrollable, what am i doing wrong?**

**ADDITION:**

My code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.iboRealScroolView.contentSize = self.iboRealImage.image.size;
self.iboRealScroolView.zoomScale=2;
NSLog(@"CONTENT HEIGHT: %f",self.iboRealScroolView.contentSize.height);
NSLog(@"CONTENT WIDTH: %f",self.iboRealScroolView.contentSize.width);

NSLog(@"FRAME HEIGHT: %f",self.iboRealScroolView.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"FRAME WIDTH: %f",self.iboRealScroolView.frame.size.width);
}
```

Output:

```
2014-07-09 12:31:52.493 edheth[1810:60b] CONTENT HEIGHT: 1536.000000
2014-07-09 12:31:52.494 edheth[1810:60b] CONTENT WIDTH: 982.000000
2014-07-09 12:31:52.495 edheth[1810:60b] FRAME HEIGHT: 808.000000
2014-07-09 12:31:52.495 edheth[1810:60b] FRAME WIDTH: 531.000000
```

Comment: Your contentSize isn't larger than the size of the UIScrollView.

Comment: u were added the scrolview.delegate =self

Comment: Jeff, is.
Anbu.Karthik, added it in designer and also just tried in code - nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code, if your `UIScrollView` isn't scrollable this is usually because your `UIScrollView's` `contentSize` is smaller than or equal to the size of the `UIScrollView's` `frame`.

Example:

```
myScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,500,500);
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
```

[UIScrollView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Solution : Set Minimum & Maximum zoom Scale. Default is both 1.0.

```
[self.iboRealScroolView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
[self.iboRealScroolView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
```

Also Set delegate of UIScrollView and implement below methods.

```
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    return Your_ImageView;
}
```

Comment: Please check my edited solution. I think so it's work for you.

Comment: already was. if it wasn't implemented my zoom wouldn't work =)